# Multi Search Not Possible Within a Mapped Index?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following mapping:

```json
    {
        "hero_index": {
            "mappings": {
                "dynamic": "strict",
                "properties": {
                    "name": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "super_power": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "weakness": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

All good until I want to `https://localhost:9200/super_heroes/_msearch` with a body that looks like:

```json
         [
            {"query": {"term": {"name": {"term": "Hulk"}}}},
            {"index": "super_heroes"},
            {"query": {"term": {"word": {"term": "Iron Man"}}}}
    
         ]
```

But I get the following error...

```json
    {
        "error": {
            "root_cause": [
                {
                    "type": "x_content_parse_exception",
                    "reason": "[1:2] Unexpected close marker ']': expected '}' (for root starting at [Source: (org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.ByteBufferStreamInput); line: 1, column: 0])\n at [Source: (org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.ByteBufferStreamInput); line: 1, column: 2]"
                }
            ],
            "type": "x_content_parse_exception",
            "reason": "[1:2] Unexpected close marker ']': expected '}' (for root starting at [Source: (org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.ByteBufferStreamInput); line: 1, column: 0])\n at [Source: (org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.ByteBufferStreamInput); line: 1, column: 2]",
            "caused_by": {
                "type": "json_parse_exception",
                "reason": "Unexpected close marker ']': expected '}' (for root starting at [Source: (org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.ByteBufferStreamInput); line: 1, column: 0])\n at [Source: (org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.ByteBufferStreamInput); line: 1, column: 2]"
            }
        },
        "status": 400
    }
```

I am not sure why that is or how to fix it... any ideas?

Comment: How are you sending the requests? Node.js, CURL, Java?

Comment: @MilenGeorgiev Well... raw http, JSON, I don't wanna rely on a library... also, I am using RUST in case you find a way to do so in rust I would accept it... I am also hosting my cluster myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `_msearch` query accepts body in this format:

```json
{metadata}
{query}
{metadata}
{query}
```

You're trying to send a JSON array, this is why you get an error.

Try this (note, first blank object is required, since you're not sending any metadata):

```json
{ }
{"query": {"term": {"name": {"term": "Hulk"}}}},
{"index": "super_heroes"},
{"query": {"term": {"word": {"term": "Iron Man"}}}}
```

[Source](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html)

Comment: No way! I went over those docs like twice and never did that cuz postman gives me red squiggly lines but it does work. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah - the whole body is not a valid JSON object, but each line is valid on its own.

Comment: I will make sure to put you in my list of super heroes, thanks.